# ITextSharp VB.net equivalent

Tags: vb.net

I am using iTextSharp in VB.net. I have this piece of code from java

```
mainTable.WidthPercentage(New Single() {100, 0}, pageSize)
```

what is the equivalent for this in VB.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mainTable.WidthPercentage(New Single() {100, 0}, pageSize)
```